# Twilio - Using Classic Functions How do I just create and update variables that persist?

Tags: variables, twilio, sms

Here's the start of my code using NodeJS

Now I want to know how to create a variable, modify the variable and update the variable in a way that persists between calls and sessions.

I want to be able to have different users SMS me, and I will reply to each with a different index that is incrementing.

I dont need the full solution, I just need to know how a persistent variable can be created, recalled, changed and saved for later.

```
/* global module, exports, require, process, console */
'use strict'

// Configure necessary Twilio objects
const twilio = require('twilio')
const client = twilio(process.env.ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.AUTH_TOKEN)
const notify = client.notify.services(process.env.TTK_BROADCAST_NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID)

// List of admin phone numbers should be in the system environment
const adminNumbers = process.env.TTK_BROADCAST_ADMIN_NUMBERS
```

so something like ...

```
// Helper class for commands
class Command {
  // Create a new instance with necessary arguments from the incoming SMS
  constructor(event, context) {
    this.fromNumber = event.From
    this.body = event.Body || ''
    this.event = event
    this.context = context

    // Occassionally, US numbers will be passed without the preceding
    // country code - check for this eventuality and fix it
    if (this.fromNumber.indexOf('+') !== 0) {
      this.fromNumber = `+1${this.fromNumber}`
    }
  }

  // Get an array of arguments after the first word for a command
  get commandArguments() {
    return this.body.trim().split(' ').slice(1)
  }

  // Get the full text after the command with spaces reinserted
  get commandText() {
    return this.commandArguments.join(' ')
  }

  // Execute command async (to be overridden by subclasses)
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, 'Command not implemented.')
  }
}

/* Subclasses for supported commands */

class HelpCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, helpMessage)
  }
}

// INCOMING MESSAGES SIGN UP ##########################
class SubscribeCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    notify.bindings.create({
      identity: this.fromNumber,
      bindingType: 'sms',
      address: this.fromNumber,
      tag: ['subscribe']
    }).then((response) => {

/***
1. Increment a variable here.
2. inject the variable into subscrubeSuccessMessage as the subscriber index.
***/
      callback(null, subscribeSuccessMessage)
    }).catch(err => {
      callback(err, subscribeFailMessage)
    })
  }
}
```

Now I have found this documentation
https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/variable

The main problem I'm having is that I don't know where these environment SIDs come from????. Can I ignore it?

Could I do something like this, and just leave environments blank?

```
client.serverless.services('ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                 .environments
                 .variables
                 .create({key: 'key', value: 'value'})
                 .then(variable => console.log(variable.sid));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the below example, it is one option to persist data. Sync has specific constraints which are detailed [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/limits#sync-payload-limits), but it may meet your use case.

Function environmental variables aren't designed to store dynamic data. There is an example of it being used that way, [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-round-robin-call-forwarding-studio-functions).

[Use Twilio Sync to create, read, update, delete persistent data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-use-twilio-sync-to-create-read-update-delete-persistent-data)

Comment: Thanks alan, the only problem I had with Sync, was that it is not clear where the Sync Service SID's come from. syncServiceSid='???????'

I have not had good luck findin info about the dependencies or processes required to create these IDs? That includes IDs for environments and other services.

Comment: It is covered in the comments in the code:
```  // View Sync Services - https://www.twilio.com/console/sync/services
  // Set to a specific Sync Service SID```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else trying to solve something like this.

I ended up solving this by using Axios and made a remote connection to my web server as per this document

https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-read-request-to-an-external-api

After employing this I had the option to use a database or to just use flat files to persist data. I knocked up a quick solve with flat files as I didn't need anything too complex.

In my application the administrator broadcasts an announcement of an upcoming event, and assigns the event a new ID, 'eventid'. The server side PHP code is set to respond to Create Commands which will create a new set of records in a folder and flush the indexes (not included here).

Upon receipt the user has the option to RSVP, but they must also enter the eventid. 'RSVP EVENTID'.

I needed persistence because every RSVP requires a unique SEAT_ID, and I don't want the system to create duplicates or assign more than 1 SEAT_ID per phone number (user).

So the admin creates an Event, and then users respond via RSVP EVENTID and everyone gets a unique seat#.

axios allows you to just use GET/POST and JSON to pass data back and forth.

SERVER SIDE PHP, quick test of persistent data. This creates a unique index for each phone number, starting at 11. (So I can reserve seats 0-10)

```
<?PHP
//count.php (needs local read/write permissions)
$number= isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : "555-123-4567";
$number= cleanInput($number);

$eventid= isset($_GET['eventid']) ? $_GET['eventid'] : 127;
$eventid= cleanInput($eventid);

if(!file_exists($eventid)){
    mkdir($eventid);
    $status="Unknown Event";
}else{
    $status="Ok";
}

$uniqueness = intval(file_get_contents("{$eventid}/" . $number ));
if(!$uniqueness){
    $seat = intval(file_get_contents("{$eventid}/count.txt"));
    $seat = $seat<11 ? 11 : $seat+1;
    file_put_contents("{$eventid}/count.txt", $seat . "");
    file_put_contents("{$eventid}/" . $number , $seat . "");
}else{
    $seat=$uniqueness;
}

/*
populate the other data, however you like
*/

$output= "{";
$output.= " \"seat\": \"" . $seat . "\"";
$output.= " \"status\": \"" . $status . "\"";
$output.= ",\"eventid\": \"" . $eventid . "\"";
$output.= ",\"number\": \"" . $number . "\"";
$output.= "}";

echo $output;

function cleanInput($cleanme){
$cleaned=str_replace("+","",$cleanme);
$cleaned=str_replace(".","",$cleaned);
$cleaned=str_replace('\\',"",$cleaned);
$cleaned=str_replace('/',"",$cleaned);
return $cleaned;
}
```

Now I can use a webhook via get to create indexes for the replies.
First you have to add the axios dependencies.. then prepare a response to your users post. In my case I've splitting the user input up into a command and argument.

NODJS in twilio classic function.

```
/*
This application is part of the Twilio.org Toolkit for Nonprofits.
For complete documentation on how to use this function, please visit:

https://github.com/Twilio-org/toolkit/blob/master/docs/broadcast.md
*/

// Configure necessary Twilio objects
const twilio = require('twilio');
const axios  = require('axios');

...

class RSVPCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Reply to RSVP with a unique seat #
    axios
      .get('https://MY_SERVER.com/smsapi/count.php?number=' + this.fromNumber + '&eventid=' + eventid)
      .then((response) => {
        let { seat, eventid } = response.data;
        let msg = "Thank you! Seat #%seat% has been reserved for you for Event#%eventid%  Present this message for entry. See you there!"
        msg = msg.replace("%seat%",seat);
        msg = msg.replace("%eventid%",eventid);
        callback(null, msg)
    }).catch(err => {
      callback(err, subscribeFailMessage)
    })  
  }
}

//The export handler looks something like

// Handle incoming SMS commands ####################
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  // Get command text from incoming SMS body
  let body = event.Body || ''

//EXTRACT THE COMMAND AND eventid ARGUMENT
  cmd = body.trim().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase()
  //assuming an RSVP or EVENT command, capture the event ID
  eventid = body.trim().split(' ')[1].toLowerCase()

  // Default to help command
  let cmdInstance = new HelpCommand(event, context)
    
  // Choose other commands as appropriate
  switch(cmd) {
    case 'subscribe': cmdInstance = new SubscribeCommand(event, context); break;
    
    case 'broadcast': cmdInstance = new BroadcastCommand(event, context); break;
    //this is where we send a special create command to initiate the event.
    //(not included)     
    case 'event': cmdInstance = new BroadcastEventCommand(event, context); break;
        
    case 'rsvp': cmdInstance = new RSVPCommand(event, context); break;
  }

  // Execute command
  cmdInstance.run((err, message) => {
    let twiml = new twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse()
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      message = 'There was a problem with your request. Try again!'
    }
    twiml.message(message)
    callback(null, twiml)
  })
}
```

TLDR; Persistent counters are maintained in flat file records on a remote server via a little PHP code. axios allows the passing of data through JSON and webhooks.